# how to create sequential animation using AnimationDrawable and animation-list

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, android-animation

I'm attempting to create a sequential loading animation that display's 5 dots which turn black one after another in order to display a loading animation. I've built the animation - but thus far - only one dot turns black - my attempt to turn the 2nd black does not seem to be working (once I figure out how to animate it I will apply the method to the remaining 3 dots - just so you know where the code sits as of now - I've only attempted to animate the 2nd dot at this point but it isn't working - the first dot blinks as it should - then nothing happens to the other 4 dots in the animation)

-Amani Swann

### SRC SNIPPET:

```
try {
        // updating layout initially has updating text with 1 dot in the xml
        setContentView(R.layout.updating);
        // This image view has the updating text to be progressively updated
        // with dots addition
        ImageView loading = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);
        //Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty);
        // Set updating button to drawable animation
        loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating1);
        loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();


        ImageView loading2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);
        //Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty);
        // Set updating button to drawable animation
        loading2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating2);
        loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading2.getBackground();
```

### ANIMATION XML SNIPPET #1:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:oneshot="false">    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_empty" android:duration="500" />    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_full" android:duration="500" />    
</animation-list>
```

### ANIMATION XML SNIPPET #2:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:oneshot="false">    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_empty" android:duration="500" />    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_full" android:duration="500" />    
</animation-list>
```

### LAYOUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/updating_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/updating_text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loading_empty1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/loading_empty2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/updating1"
        android:src="@drawable/loading_empty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loading_empty3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loading_empty2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/updating3"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loading_empty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loading_empty2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loading_empty1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/loading_empty3"
        android:background="@drawable/updating2"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loading_empty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loading_empty4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loading_empty3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/loading_empty3"
        android:background="@drawable/updating4"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loading_empty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loading_empty5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loading_empty4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/loading_empty4"
        android:background="@drawable/updating5"
        android:src="@drawable/loading_empty" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why didn't you use animation list for this? 4 dots as 1 image and each item in animation list as one frame in animation?

Like this http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/01/create-frame-animation-with.html

Answer (score 1):

this can be done using a single `ImageView`, `animation-list` and `AnimationDrawable` class of Android.

- Copying your five images in `drawable` folder.
- Create XML file in your `drawable` folder of `animation-list`.
- List all five images in this xml file.
- Set the duration of animation of each Image in xml file.
- Set your xml file as an image resource in your `ImageView`.
- Use `getDrawable()` to get each image from xml.
- Start the animation.

for instance, suppose you have created five images of dots with names **dot01.png, dot02.png, dot03.png, dot04.png, dot05..png** then your xml file in `drawable` folder should be,

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dot01"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dot02"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dot03"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dot04"
        android:duration="150"/>        
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dot05"
        android:duration="150"/>


    <!-- Reset to original -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dot01"
        android:duration="10"/>

</animation-list>
```

Now set that xml as image resource in an `ImageView` and start the animation from `start()` method of `AnimationDrawable` instance,

```
ImageView DotAnimImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
// dots_animation below is the name of your xml file.
DotAnimImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dots_animation);
// Now create a reference to getDrawable
AnimationDrawable dotsAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) DotAnimImage.getDrawable();
// Start animation
dotsAnimation.start();
```

the above code would work but it will animate the image just once , this is because of a bug in android, android thinks that the animation is still running even when its already over. The solution is to check if the animation is running using `isRunning()` method of `AndroidDrawable` instance and manually stopping it using `stop()` method,

```
//Check if animation is running and stop it,
if (dotsAnimation.isRunning()) {
    dotsAnimation.stop();
    // start again,
    dotsAnimation.start();
}
```

Your final code should be,

```
ImageView DotAnimImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
DotAnimImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dots_animation);
AnimationDrawable dotsAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) DotAnimImage.getDrawable();

if (dotsAnimation.isRunning()) {
    dotsAnimation.stop();
}

dotsAnimation.start();
```